# creating an proxy class for an webservice in vs 2005

Tags: visual-studio

i have an webservice 
1: when i add an weservice using  webreference using vs 2005  it creates me reference.cs, wsdl, disco file

2: but when i create an proxy  class using wsdl.exe
wsdl /out:myProxyClass.cs http://hostServer/WebserviceRoot/WebServiceName.asmx?WSDL
it creates only .cs  file  it  does not create an wsdl, disco  files

is  there anything we have to enable  to  get disco, wsdl files

any help  would be great

Thanks
 Prince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [disco.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)